# Make 8 rectangular images fill entire screen with native aspect ratio and fluid layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 8 identical, rectangular photos that I want to seamlessly fill my entire web page (even during resizing) in two rows, and I am not sure how to do that.

Basically I was going to make a `div` and put in all of the images at `25%` width of the parent, (That way the fifth image will flow down to the second level).

However, I am not sure if I should set the `width: 100%` or `height: 100%`.  The images are have more length than width, and I have to preserve that aspect ratio.  Obviously if someone's browser window is a square they can't fit seamlessly, I am just wondering what strategies people have used to get this four seamless row appearance.

Thanks

Comment: How about setting the images as backgrounds for divs, and then absolutely/fixed positioning the divs by percentage? For example, div.one { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 75%; bottom: 50%; } div.two { pos:abs; left: 25%; right: 50%; bottom: 50% } etc.?  Edit: Oh, and set them to background-size: cover;

Comment: I really like this solution. I have noticed very good scaling with background-size: cover and almost no distortion.  How about you? One note, I do want this images to be "content" not necessarily just background content, but I guess background-images can count as content?

Comment: This is great.  Is it absolutely necessary to set `right` and `left` offsets?

(I think you should have made this an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/HexM4/1/** <- this is probably not what you want...right?

**http://jsfiddle.net/HexM4/3/** <- how is this?

```
div {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

4 divs, 4 columns, each one 25% in width with 2 images stacked inside of it verticaly. To prevent ugly whitespace, "display: block;" on img elements as well.

P.S.: Of course if all images in one row have the same height, you're settled. Any of those 2 jsfiddles should make you happy.

EDIT: Oops, misunderstanding?

Of course you cannot always fill 100% of both width and height (and not more than 100%!) with 2 rows of images, at least not without affecting their aspect ratio. Or cutting them in half here or there, in case you add many many images to each column in my example (+"overflow: hidden;" on parent div, which is absolutely positioned (or fixed) and sized at 100% of height and 100% of width of user's browser window). No solid solution I can possibly think of.

tl;dr: aspect ratio of user's viewport can, and does differ from one to the other. No, you can't always fit the same 8 pictures in it without changing their aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, I agree, sort of asking for the impossible here, but I think this is a good method.  I hate to use all the `divs`, but this is a difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Putting my comment into a more well thought out answer this morning. This one uses image elements as opposed to CSS backgrounds.

Try something like this, perhaps?

http://jsfiddle.net/d58Az/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="two"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="three"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="four"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="five"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="six"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="seven"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
    <div class="eight"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></div>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.one,
.two,
.three,
.four,
.five,
.six,
.seven,
.eight {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.one, .two, .three, .four {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
}
.five, .six, .seven, .eight {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
.one, .five {
    right: 75%;
    left: 0;
}
.two, .six {
    right: 50%;
    left: 25%;
}
.three, .seven {
    right: 25%;
    left: 50%;
}
.four, .eight {
    left: 75%;
    right: 0;
}
```

In certain browsers the two rows won't line up absolutely perfectly, so I might try overlapping them a tiny bit (eg. Give .one, .two, .three and .four a bottom value of 50.5%).

Note that if you care about IE 8 you'll likely need to position the image with JS instead of CSS, as transform is not supported.

edit: To answer your question, "Is it absolutely necessary to set right and left offsets?" – not both of them, no. However I'm using them instead of declaring explicit widths. Setting left: 25%; and right: 50%; is more or less equivalent to left: 25%; width: 25%;  It's just a matter of preference, really!

Comment: Now we are talking, it has the `imag` so that they are actual content, but it seems that the `background-size: cover` provides a bit better scaling of the images. Do you notice the same?